# Trying to complete sumifs(?) script

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to complete a script that will add together values in C if the date is of the selected month and is in the proper team.
Example:

```
|  Team|  Date|  Cost|
|   102|Mar-17| 13245|
|   103|Jan-17|  2050|
|   101|Feb-17|  1245|
|   104|Jan-17| 12400|
|   102|Mar-17|  5242|
|   104|Jan-17|   600|
|   102|Feb-17| 10240|
|   102|Jan-17|   450|
|   102|Mar-17| 12245|
|   101|Jan-17|  2300|
```

The objective would be for the script to determine if I am looking for january:

- 101 = 2300
- 102 = 450
- 103 = 2050
- 104 = 13000

I have been trying to figure this out and feel stuck. In the formula provided, cboMonth is determined from a userform and its combobox as a three letter month. cboYear is determined in a similar manner with 4-digits. The initial plan was to use a loop, but I dont know how to put together a summing function into the mix. This is what I have so far.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim txt101 As Long
Dim txt102 As Long
Dim txt103 As Long
Dim txt104 As Long
Dim txt105 As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


ReportWbk.Sheets(cboYear).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each x In Range("D" & lastrow)
    If x.Value = "FG-25" And x.Offset(, 1).Format(Month(mmm)) = cboMonth Then
        txt101 =
        txt102 =
        txt103 =
        txt104 =
        txt105 =
    End If
Next x
```

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. This quite obviously is in a workbook, as your code references `ReportWbk`.

Comment: Is the data in your "Date" column stored as dates (formatted in a `"mmm-yy"` format) or is it just text?

Comment: @YowE3K "mmm-yy"

Comment: Are they always a particular day of the month (e.g. 1st of the month? last day of the month?) or are they various dates throughout the month (i.e. the `SUMIFS` needs to select any dates >= 1st of the month and <= last day of the month)?

Comment: Verious dates throughout the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "Team" is in column A, "Date" is in column B, "Cost" is in column C, and that your variables `cboMonth` and `cboYear` are of type `String`, you should be able to do:

```
'Convert input to a date
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = DateValue("1 " & cboMonth & " " & cboYear)
'Perform the required SUMIFS
txt101 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C:C"), _
                                              Range("A:A"), "101", _
                                              Range("B:B"), ">=" & myDate, _
                                              Range("B:B"), "<=" & DateAdd("m", 1, myDate))
'txt102 = 
'txt103 = 
'txt104 =
'txt105 =
```

I'm not clear as to how your data is structured, but that shouldn't be too hard to integrate into your code.

Comment: Ah! `Application.WorksheetFunction` Everywhere I had looked was just saying `.SumIfs(...` Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Thelnternet `Application.SumIfs(...` would also work.  (As would `With Application.WorksheetFunction` // `.SumIfs(...` // `End With`, and `With Application` // `.SumIfs(...` // `End With`)